# Which Android devices should I test against?

Tags: android, testing, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hardware devices do you test your Android apps on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278559/what-hardware-devices-do-you-test-your-android-apps-on)

I'm porting my iPhone app over to Android, planning on releasing it in the Google and Amazon AppStores.  I'm planning on targeting OS versions 2.2 and 2.3, as they have the highest market share.

But, what devices have the highest market share?  I want to make sure I test on the "common" devices, and so I'm looking for resources / recommendations about which devices to include in my testing regimen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends the target country as the market share of a device varies.
I would recommend covering some of the following attributes

Devices with screens : ldpi, mdpi and hdpi
Devices with screen sizes : small screen (3 inches), normal screen ( 4 inches ) large screen ; 7 inches or more

Refer to the platform versions link for more details
    http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Answer (score 2):

There are no dominating phone models in the android world. My app supports 2.2+ (API 8).  The top three phones models among its users are Galaxy S2 7%, EVO 7% and Galaxy S 2.7% with a long tail of 'other models'. Welcome to the free world. ;-)

From compatability view point, it is safer, if you can live with it, not to use targetSdkVersion and to have minSdkVersion == target SDK version (as you set in eclipse).

Also, make sure to test in portrait and landscape (unless if your app is limited to a single app) including transitions mid activity.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, As long as your app working on target OS, device shouldn't be an issue. Anyway, you may try on samsung galaxy, HTC etc., By the way you may need to make sure it is working for different resolutions.