# Which Android hardware devices should I test on?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hardware devices do you test your Android apps on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278559/what-hardware-devices-do-you-test-your-android-apps-on)

I'm trying to compile a list of Android hardware devices that it would make sense to buy and test against if you want to target an as broad audience as possible, while still not buying every single Android device out there.

I know there's a lot of information regarding screen sizes and Android versions available elsewhere, but:

1. when developing for Android it's not terribly useful to know if the screen size of a device is 480x800 or 320x240, unless you feel like doing the math to convert that into Android "units" (i.e. small, normal, large or xlarge screens, and ldpi, mdpi, hdpi or xhdpi densities).
2. Even knowing the dimensions of a device, you cannot be sure of the actual Android units as there's some overlap, see [Range of screens supported in the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range)

Taking into account the distribution of [Platform versions](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) and [Screen Sizes and Densities](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html), below is my current list based on information from the Wikipedia article on [Comparison of Android devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices).

I'm fairly sure the information in this list is correct, but I'd welcome any suggestions/changes.

**Phones**

```
| Model                   | Android Version | Screen Size | Density |

| HTC Wildfire            |      2.1/2.2    |     Normal  |  mdpi   |

| HTC Tattoo              |      1.6        |     Normal  |  mdpi   |

| HTC Hero                |      2.1        |     Normal  |  mdpi   |

| HTC Legend              |      2.1        |     Normal  |  mdpi   |

| Sony Ericsson Xperia X8 |      1.6/2.1    |     Normal  |  mdpi   |

| Motorola Droid          |      2.0-2.2    |     Normal  |  hdpi   |

| Samsung Galaxy S II     |      2.3        |     Normal  |  hdpi   |

| Samsung Galaxy Nexus    |      4.0        |     Normal  |  xhdpi  |

| Samsung Galaxy S III    |      4.0        |     Normal  |  xhdpi  |




**Tablets**

| Model                   | Android Version | Screen Size | Density |

| Samsung Galaxy Tab 7"   |      2.2        |     Large   |  hdpi   |

| Samsung Galaxy Tab 10"  |      3.0        |     X-Large |  mdpi   |

| Asus Transformer Prime  |      4.0        |     X-Large |  mdpi   |

| Motorola Xoom           |    3.1/4.0      |     X-Large |  mdpi   |
```

**N.B.**: I have seen (and read) other posts on SO on this subject, e.g. [Which Android devices should I test against?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829348/which-android-devices-should-i-test-against) and [What hardware devices do you test your Android apps on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278559/what-hardware-devices-do-you-test-your-android-apps-on) but they don't seem very canonical. Maybe this should be marked community wiki?

Comment: I would add a Motorola Tablet (xoom?), and Motorola phone(attrix/photon,droid something?). Depending on your what your applications do motoblur can have an effect on them, it'd be good to at least try out on big, and one small moto device.

Comment: I've made a bigger list! http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a "slider" ie. Motorola Droid in your list. I would recommend adding one, otherwise looks like a pretty good list. :0)